# jQuery if statement, Data correct but dosen't pass thorough

Tags: jquery, date, if-statement

I am having an issue with an if statement which is giving me the right data but no passing through... SO:

i have

-- Hidden Carrier --

```
<div id="HiddenCurrentDate">
<?php
$CurrentDate = date('d-m-y');
echo $CurrentDate;
?>
</div>
```

-- row --

```
<td class="WDClass"><div id="WDD'.$row["id"].'" class="WDDiv">'. 
$row["StartDate"] .'</div></td>
```

-- jQuery --

```
var CurrentDate = $("#HiddenCurrentDate").text();
var StartedDates = $(".WDDiv");

$(StartedDates).each(function() {

var DateID = '#' + $(this).attr('id');    
var DateString1 = $(DateID).text();
if(CurrentDate === DateString1){
    alert('Match');
}else{
    alert('No Match: current-' + CurrentDate + " -  Row " + DateString1 );
}

});
```

So this here when effected gives me the correct date when called... But it does not pass through the if it just gets "ELSED" :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might have spaces and would be better if you `trim()` them off.

Either trim them off at the start:

```
var CurrentDate = $("#HiddenCurrentDate").text().trim();
```

Or trim them here:

```js
if (CurrentDate.trim() === DateString1.trim()) {
//-------------^^^^^^^----------------^^^^^^^
  alert('Match');
} else {
  alert('No Match: current-' + CurrentDate + " -  Row " + DateString1);
}
```

Comment: THAAAAAAANKYOU you are a star :)... Fixed my issue :).